# Convergence in $L^{\infty}$ and $L^1$

Tags: integration, general-topology, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^j \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^j$, a continuous function.

Now, if we assume that $(x_n)_n \subset L^{\infty}([0,1],\mathbb{R}^j)$ that converges to $x \in L^{\infty}([0,1],\mathbb{R}^j)$. We deduce that $f(x_n(t))\rightarrow f(x(t))$ (since $f$ is continuous).

But If we assume that $x_n,x \in  L^1([0,1],\mathbb{R}^j)$, do we still have: $f(x_n(t))\rightarrow f(x(t))$ ?

My idea:

Probbaly no, but we have a convergent subsequence $(x_{\phi(n)})_n$ almost everywhere. Hence we have

$$f(x_{\phi(n)}(t))\rightarrow f(x(t)).$$

I want to know if either my statement or my idea are wrong.

Comment: The question is unclear, $f(x_n)$ has no sense, $x_n\in L^\infty $ whereas $f:\mathbb R^j\to \mathbb R^j$.

Comment: In what sense do you want convergence of $f(x_n)$ to $f(x)$?

Comment: I assume that $f(x_n)$ is actually $f\circ x_n$ and convergence is in $L^1$ space.

Comment: I corrected it, I think now the question is clear